# Is it possible complete a $3\times3$ magic square such that

Tags: matrices, arithmetic, magic-square

Is it possible complete a $3\times3$ magic square such that the constant is equal to $(-22)$ and the initial form is :
$$ \left[ \begin{array} {ccc}
 b& (+2) &  a \\
 d & c &  (-34) \\ 
 e & f & (+8)
\end{array} \right]$$
I found different possibilities for $a,\ b, \ c, \ d, \ e, \ f$ so it seems that this magic square is not solvable.

What would be interesting to change ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: When you say the constant is equal to $-22$, do you mean the sums of the rows, columns, and diagonals are all to be $-22$?  Because a magic square of the form you suggest is possible, but the sum of each line must be $-30$.

Comment: @paw88789 Indeed, I was misreading ! It's better now, thank you !

Comment: In a magic square the center is always $\frac{\Sigma}3$ so with $\Sigma=-22$ you cannot have integer solution since this number is not divisible by $3$. If you take $\Sigma=-21$ instead and $-34\to -28$ it works too.

Comment: You will not be able to have whole numbers in the square and a magic sum of $-22$.  The magic sum must be three times the center square.   Are you willing to have fractions?  In that case, remove one of your three numbers, put $-\frac {22}3$ in the center, and solve for the rest.  It should come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{bmatrix}4 &9 & 2\\3 & 5& 7\\8 & 1& 6 \end{bmatrix}is a magic matrix, add unknoun to the matrix to find what you want. 
\begin{bmatrix}4+x &9+x & 2+x\\3+x & 5+x& 7+x\\8+x & 1+x & 6+x \end{bmatrix} so 
$$(4+x)+(5+x)+(6+x)=-22\\15+3x=-22 \to 3x=-15-22\\3x=-37\\x=-\frac{37}{3}$$so initial value is $1+x=1-\frac{37}{3}$ there is not an integer solution for the table.
but if $-22$ was for example $-21$ then $$3x=-15-21=-36\\\to 1+x=-11 $$

Comment: You implicitly say that all magic squares need be in the form $\text{Square}_{ref}+X$, can you share a link for that assertion ?

Comment: No,but every magic matrix can build of this one by adding or subtracting numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your initial values give an unique solution for a magic square.

I've calculated
$ Q = \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 -28 & 2 & -4 \\ 
 14 & -10 & -34 \\ 
 -16 & -22 & 8
 \end{bmatrix}$  - but it has the "magic sum" $m=-30$.

*Remark: Since I see a $-22$ in the last row: did you perhaps mess your initial structure?*

---

***Background:***
Re-naming the entries in your matrix $Q$  in the following way:
$ Q = \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b & c \\ 
 d & e & f \\ 
 g & h & i
 \end{bmatrix}$
gives with a simple matrix-multiplication by a coefficients matrix $C$ , matrix of initial values $A=[b,f,i] = [2,-34,8] $ the resulting values for $R=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]$  by

$$ C\cdot A= R \qquad : \qquad \small \begin{array} {}
 & * & \begin{bmatrix} b \\ f \\ i \end{bmatrix} \\ 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 -3/2 & 1/2 & 2  \\ 
 -1 & 0 & 2  \\ 
 -1/2 & 1/2 & 1  \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 
 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 
 -2 & 1 & 2  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} & = & 
 \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{array}$$
Having $R$, the matrix $Q$ can then be formed by simple quadratic $3\times3$ - arrangement of the computed values in $R$

*You may like to read about this calculation-ansatz in this [text](https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/Helms_2022_magicSquareOfSquares2_draft.pdf) where I discuss the magic square with squared entries; however the initial ansatz is general and not confined to squared entries.*